# Strange Behavior on Global and Local Variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope

I tried following code:

```
var a = 5;

function x() {
  console.log(a);
}

x();
```

It runs as expected and prints 5.

But i changed the code so the global variable a will be overwrite as follows:

```
var a = 5;

function x() {
  console.log(a);
  var a = 1;
}

x();
```

It prints undefined. It doesn't make sense for me since the overwrite should be happened right after console.log(a). So what is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because your second `a` variable is being 'hoisted' to the top of the function and it hides the first `a`. What is actually happening is this:

```
var a = 5;

function x() {
  var a;
  console.log(a);
  a = 1;
}

x();
```

[Here is an article on hoisting from adequately good](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) for further reading on the subject.

Comment: When variable gets hoisted its value also doesnt get hoisted? For example why wasnt the expression var a =1; hoisted. And why just var a;

Comment: The value isn't hoisted because you set it at that position, consider an example of initialising a variable to be equal to the contents of another variable which wouldn't have been filled at the start of the function. Setting it to 1 would break the flow of the program.

Comment: Wew. It is still hard for me to accept the scoping & hoisting concept. I come from java and i think javascript scoping is a little bit strange. Anyway thanks for the answer and the article.

Comment: http://www.jslint.com/ actually complains if you don't define all of a function's variables at the beginning, the thinking behind that is you wouldn't run into these sort of issues that would be very difficult to debug.

Comment: Cool. So for the best practice, all variables inside a function should be declared at the top. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = 5;

function x() {
    var a = 1;
console.log(a);
}

x();
```

you need to initalize variable a before console.log();