# Global variable override with a local one

Tags: javascript

The following test is a success, and prints `1` and `1`:

```
function test1() {
    a = 1;
    console.log(a); // prints "1"
}
function test2() {
    console.log(a); // prints "1"
}
test1();
test2();
```

And the following test fails, because a local variable overrides the previously created global one:

```
function test1() {
    a = 1;
    var a = 2;
    console.log(a); // prints "2"
}
function test2() {
    console.log(a); // throws an error
}
test1();
test2();
```

Why does the second example remove the global variable permanently? What purpose/logic does such functionality serve in JavaScript?

**EDITED:** For those who marked it as a duplicate of [Strange Behavior on Global and Local Variable in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714752/strange-behavior-on-global-and-local-variable-in-javascript)

Hoisting refers to the scenario when a later declared local variable is moved up the function scope, overriding the previously visible variable. But in our case the function first creates a global variable, and then deletes it completely/globally.

However, it is probably related, as we can see in the following test:

```
function test1() {
    a = 1;
    console.log(a); // prints "1"
}
function test2() {
    console.log(a); // prints "undefined"
    var a = 2;
}
function test3() {
    console.log(a); // prints "1"
}
test1();
test2();
test3();
```

Comment: JavaScript hoists the declaration of variables to the top of the function.

Comment: There is no global variables in your example.. They are all local vars..

Comment: @YacoZaragoza, if that were the case, test2() in the first example would have failed.

Comment: In your second example, the global is never referenced. The code becomes: `function test1() { var a; a = 1; a = 2; console.log(a); }` due to [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting).

Comment: See jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ut29hgmt/

Comment: "*But in our case the function first creates a global variable*" -- No, the second example *never* creates a global variable.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, how would you then explain in the last piece of code where `test3()` prints `1`?

Comment: @vitaly-t: That's entirely different. Running `test1()` first in that case *does* create a global variable.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, yeah, I see what you mean now.

Comment: @vitaly-t Are you convinced now? The additions to your question in later edits are still caused by the same issue (hoisting a variable declaration to the top of the function): `function test2() { var a; console.log(a); a = 2; }`. When viewed like this, it's obvious why it prints `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second case, no global variable named `a` ever exists.

`a = 1` generally does not create a global variable. The statement `a = 1` stores the value `1` in a variable called `a`. If the variable environment of any containing local scope has a variable called `a`, the nearest scope with an `a` variable will have that variable set to `1`.

As a special case, if a variable called `a` does *not* exist in any containing scope (and if you are not in strict mode), then the JavaScript engine will create a global variable called `a`.

In your second case, `var a` creates an `a` variable in the local scope. Due to hoisting, that modification to the scope's variable environment happens before any code runs. Thus, by the time `a = 1` is executed, that local scope does have a variable called `a`, so that local variable is used.

In your third case, `test2` logs the local variable `a` (created by the `var a`). At the time the `log` call is made, the local `a` has not yet been assigned a value.

---

> Hoisting refers to the scenario when a later declared local variable is moved up the function scope, overriding the previously visible variable.

Hoisting simply means that all `var` declarations are treated as if they happen at the top of their containing function. It has nothing to do (directly) with overriding variable visibility.

Note that declarations with an assignment will have only the declaration hoisted, not the assignment. The assignment stays in place wherever it is in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript moves variable declarations to the top. So in this example the compiler reads you code as:

```
function test1() {
    var a;
    a = 1;
    a = 2;
    console.log(a); // prints "2"
}
function test2() {
    console.log(a); // throws an error
}
test1();
test2();
```